# Exporting/Extracting data from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, etl, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

New in GAE development and have some question regarding extracting data.

I have an app that collects data from end users and data is stored in high availability datastore, and there is a need to send subset of data the app collected to business partners on a regular basis.

Here are my questions,
1. How can I backup data in the datastore on a regular basis, say daily incremental backup and weekly full backup?
2. what are the best practices to generate daily data dump files that can be downloaded or send to my partners in a secured approach. I expect few hundred MB data files everyday and eventually will be in few GB range.
3. Can my business partners be authenticated though basic HTTP auth, or have to use OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Google is in effect backing up your data by storing it in multiple data centres.

You can however use the bulk loader if desired and back it up manually:

[Uploading and Downloading Data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata)

You can authenticate users however you choose, it's totally up to you. The "users" service is integrated into app engine directly however so if everybody has or could have google accounts that's even easier for you to use.

[The users service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers)

Due to the size of your files unless you want to piece them together from the datastore you'll have to use something else, as the datastore has a 1MB limit per model. It's perfectly possible to do that however.

But you should probably look at [The Google Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/) instead as there are no file size limits.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Appreciate your help.